# Link records in two tables without extra SubmitChanges

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Given two tables, where one is bound to another:

Items

SubItems

The Items table has an ID field with Identity Seed.

Here's the problem: to add SubItems to an Item, it's necessary to first save the Item, so the ID is generated. An extra call to `DataContext.SubmitChanges` is required before SubItems can be added and submitted.

Is there any way to set up the identity to allow just a single SubmitChanges call to save both the Item and SubItems at once?

One solution could be getting the IdentitySeed manually - but here is an issue with multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mapping between the Item and SubItems tables
you only need to link it like that

```
var yourItem = new Item();
...
var subItem = new SubItem();
...
yourItem.SubItems.Add(subItem );
dataContext.Items.Add(yourItem);
dataContext.SubmitChanges();
```